# How to create dynamically TextFiled or Text Grid like in this screenshot?

Tags: flutter, listview, grid, textfield, expandablelistview

[image]

Tried to get it by adding dynamically `SizedBox(child:Text('XVI', style:TextStyle(...),),)` to `ListView` and repeat it on every `onPressed` event of `TextButton`. But didn't get it. Is there any alternative way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
Wrap(
        spacing: 5,
        runSpacing: 5,
        children: List.generate(
          20, // Here add the list length
          (index) {
            return Container(
              color: index.isEven ? Colors.black : Colors.grey, // Change the background color based on your condition
              child: Text("XXIV", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: How I couldn't think of a `Wrap` Widget,  I did not even use a Wrap word while asking the question. Thank you I will try.